# How do I remove urls except for bbcode

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, pcre

okay i have had some php issue...
basically im trying to prevent links in my site.... to prevent spam
I got some with it but i still wanna let players post images ...
Can you help?

**Here is what im typing**

```
Img
[img]http://www.blank........gif[/img]
link
http://www.blank...........=compose&ID=1
...
test
test
.com
.biz
.net
.org
test
...
Img
[img]http://www.blank..........gif[/img]
```

**Here is what I want to change to(php wise)**

```
Img
 Show Image(since its inside [img] brackets)
link
[URL removed]
...
test
test
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
test
...
Img
 Show Image(since its inside [img] brackets)
```

---

```
$msg = trim(preg_replace('#([^\s]*)(http://|\.com|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.pt|\.php|ref\=| www| DOT )([^\s]*)#i' , ' [URL removed] ', $msg));
*This works perfect.... except... dont allow images*

$msg = preg_replace( array('#(?<!\[img\])(http://)#i' , '#(\.com|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.pt| DOT | www|ref\=|\.php)#i' ) , '[URL removed]', $msg);
*this does this*


Img
(broken Image)
link
[URL removed]www.blank[URL removed]/mailbox[URL removed]?action=compose&ID=1
...
test
test
awww
www
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
[URL removed]
test
...
Img
(broken Image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Regular expressions guru but I think that should do the work:

```
<?php

$pattern = "Img
[img]     http://www.blank........gif[/img]
link
http://www.blank...........=compose&ID=1
...
test
test
.com
.biz
.net
.org
test
...
Img
[img]http://www.blank..........gif[/img]";

$pattern = preg_replace('#\[img\](\s)*#i','[img]', $pattern);

$pattern = preg_replace('#(?<!\[img\])((http(s|):\/\/|ftp(s|):\/\/)(\S*)\.(\S*)|(\S*\.(com|net|org|biz|info)))(?!\[\\img\])(?:(?=(\s|\Z)))#i','[URL removed]',$pattern);


echo nl2br($pattern);
```

The first preg_replace is made to remove whitespaces after `[img]` that cause problems in second replacements. If you comment first preg_replace you will see that in the exact `$pattern` I inserted also link inside `[img]` would be replaced.

Of course I put into pattern only sample domains `(com|net|org|biz|info)` you should probably fill it with more: ru, uk and so on.

Comment: thanks.. thhe only othher things  is spammers doing
    www . blank . com / ref=123